# Долго загружаются тяжелые фрагменты

Tags: java, android, android-fragment, память, fragment-transaction

### Что имею?

---

У меня есть активность - `MainActivity`, которая служит контейнером для 5 фрагментов.

Переключение фрагментов идет по нажатию на BottomNavigationView, вот так -
(Объекты фрагментов были инициализированы в методе OnCreate() и вынесены в поля класса)

```
 @Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
    if(item.getItemId() != view.getSelectedItemId()) {
        fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

        if (menuItems.indexOf(item.getItemId()) > menuItems.indexOf(view.getSelectedItemId())) {
            fragmentTransaction.setCustomAnimations(R.animator.fragment_slide_left_anim, R.animator.fragment_slide_right_anim);
        } else {
            fragmentTransaction.setCustomAnimations(R.animator.fragment_slide_right_exit_anim, R.animator.fragment_slide_left_exit_anim);
        }

        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.action_contacts:
                fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.main_fragment_container, contactsFragment);
                break;
            case R.id.action_cloud:
                fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.main_fragment_container, cloudFragment);
                break;
            case R.id.action_messages:
                fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.main_fragment_container, messagesFragment);
                break;
            case R.id.action_profile:
                fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.main_fragment_container, profileFragment);
                break;
            case R.id.action_settings:
                fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.main_fragment_container, settingsFragment);
                break;
        }
        fragmentTransaction.commitAllowingStateLoss();
    }
    return true;
}
```

А вот например один из фрагментов (Этот фрагмент содержит еще в себе два фрагмента в виде `TabLayout`)

```
public class ProfileFragment extends MvpAppCompatFragment implements ProfileFView {

private MainActivity activity;

@BindView(R.id.tabs)
TabLayout tabLayout;

@BindView(R.id.viewpager)
ViewPager viewPager;

private InfoProfileFragment infoProfileFragment;
private DecorationsProfileFragment decorationsProfileFragment;

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    @SuppressLint("InflateParams") View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_profile, null);
    ButterKnife.bind(this, view);

    activity = (MainActivity) getActivity();

    infoProfileFragment = new InfoProfileFragment();
    decorationsProfileFragment = new DecorationsProfileFragment();

    setupViewPager(viewPager);
    tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);

    return view;
}

private void setupViewPager(ViewPager viewPager){
    TwoTabsViewPagerAdapter adapter = new TwoTabsViewPagerAdapter(getChildFragmentManager());
    adapter.addFragment(infoProfileFragment, "Информация");
    adapter.addFragment(decorationsProfileFragment, "Украшения");
    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
}

@Override
public void showMessage(String message) {
    Snackbar.make(activity.layout, message, Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

}

А есть практически пустые фрагменты, где только один `TextView`.

### Проблема

Загрузка пустых фрагментов происходит достаточно быстро, но вот более тяжелые фргаменты, для них занимает примерно полсекунды, чтобы показаться на экране. Это ощутимо влияет на UX.

В статических переменных я не храню контекст, так что утечки в данном случае быть не может.

---

Возможно ли это как-нибудь исправить (улучшить), либо придется смириться, что тяжелые фрагменты будут дольше загружаться?

### Заранее спасибо!

Comment: вы пробовали посмотреть в профайлер и определить куда уходит больше всего времени при открытии "тяжелого" фрагмента?